# Using white spaces in an rsync file path excecuted in a batch file

Tags: path, whitespace, rsync, spaces

So I'm using `rsync` to back up some commonly used directories, using a batch script and windows scheduler as seen here:

`rsync.bat`

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\Cygwin\bin

bash --login -i -c %1
```

I'm using Windows Scheduler to run this batch script on regular intervals, which works perfectly - until I add spaces into the file paths. Here's an example of the target paths I use on the batch file shortcuts:

Target: `C:\Cygwin\scripts\rsync.bat "rsync -vruh /cygdrive/t/uploads /cygdrive/d/Backups"`

That works perfectly. Here's the one with whitespaces:

Target: `C:\Cygwin\scripts\rsync.bat "rsync -vruh '/cygdrive/c/Users/username/My Documents' /cygdrive/d/Backups"`

Note the single quotes on the first path with whitespaces. I  can't for the life of me figure out why this won't work - I've tried backslash escaping the whitespaces, using the -s  switch, which some research solved this problem in the past, but alas, that didn't work either. Anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem of spaces is in the **argv** processing done to interpret the command line. As with any other unix application you have to escape spaces in some way on the command line or they will be used to separate arguments.

For example:

```
rsync -av host:'"a long filename"' /tmp/
rsync -av host:'a\ long\ filename' /tmp/
rsync -av host:a\\\ long\\\ filename /tmp/
```

Or use a '?' in place of a space as long as there are no other matching filenames than the one with spaces (since '?' matches any character):

```
rsync -av host:a?long?filename /tmp/
```

As long as you know that the remote filenames on the command line are interpreted by the remote shell then it all works fine.

http://rsync.samba.org/FAQ.html#9

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what I ended up doing in the past to fix it. +1

Comment: This answer is actually copied and pasted from there - http://rsync.samba.org/FAQ.html#9

Comment: The answer is correct but it should note that the space has to escaped _twice_, once for the local shell interpreting the command and once for the remote machine interpreting it again.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this having had similar problems using **rsync** in a batch file under Windows 7. The batch file code was:

```
rsync -hrtv --modify-window=3602 /cygdrive/c/Users/gavin/My Documents/ArmA Other Profiles/TheProf/ /cygdrive/h/Hobies/ARMA_BU/
```

It may just be a Windows 7 issue but the folder **gavin/My Documents** should just be **gavin/Documents**.  Additionally single quotes were needed to overcome the spaces, like:

```
rsync -hrtv --modify-window=3602 '/cygdrive/c/Users/gavin/Documents/ArmA Other Profiles/TheProf/' /cygdrive/h/Hobies/ARMA_BU/
```

Answer (score 0):

Special case:
If there are spaces in the path AND a wildcard (*), the above solutions do not seem to work (`rsync: link_stat...failed`)

Surrounding *only* the spaces with quotes seems to work.

```
/cygdrive/C/My" "Folder" "/My" "File*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The above "Surrounding ONLY the spaces with quotes seems to work" is the only solution that helped me with making a copy of a OneDrive directory with lots so spaces.  Here's the long and short of the syntax I had to use

rsync -avz --progress --exclude-from %excludefile% /cygdrive/C/Users/username/OneDrive" "-" "company1" "company2," "Inc/Documents/* /cygdrive/x/msi/MyDocuments/ --log-file=rsync-MyDocs.LOG